# Creating a "lock screen" on my application

Tags: java, lockscreen

I would like to know if it is possible to create a lock screen like panel for my application. Basically i have a program written in java and i would like to have a transparent screen (so the user still can see what is going on) but he can do nothing unless he uses a password.
I was thinking on implementing this on windows itself and not using Java frames and so on.
I found this image on the internet, it would be something like this:
[LockScreen](http://mytechquest.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Lock-Desktop-With-Transparent-Screen.jpg)

Any ideas on how can i do this?

Comment: hint: if you want desktop app use swing else look for web application.

Comment: The app is already done using swing. I just want to "lock it" the way i have described.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to lock the whole Windows environment or just your application window?

The whole desktop: you may use the class java.awt.Robot to take a screenshot of current state then make it transparent and show your custom lock screen panel over it.

More probably, you wish to lock only your application window. Use class javax.swing.JLayeredPane to draw one layer over another one. Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class LockScreen {
  private JPanel substrate;
  private JPanel upperLayer;

  public LockScreen() {
    int width = 500;
    int height = 600;

    final JButton lockButton = new JButton( "Lock" );
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        boolean lock = e.getSource() == lockButton;
        substrate.setVisible( lock );
        upperLayer.setVisible( lock );
      }
    };
    lockButton.addActionListener( actionListener );

    JPanel mainLayer = new JPanel();
    mainLayer.add( lockButton );
    mainLayer.add( new JButton( "Button" ) );
    mainLayer.add( new JLabel( "Label" ) );
    mainLayer.setBounds( 0, 0, width, height );

    final Color transparentWhite = new Color( 255, 255, 255, 127 );
    substrate = new JPanel() {
      @Override
      public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        g.setColor( transparentWhite );
        g.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );
      }
    };
    substrate.setOpaque( false );
    substrate.setBounds( 0, 0, width, height );
    substrate.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {} );
    substrate.setVisible( false );

    JButton unlockButton = new JButton( "Unlock" );
    unlockButton.addActionListener( actionListener );

    upperLayer = new JPanel();
    upperLayer.setBounds( width / 2 - 50, height / 2 - 50, 100, 100 );
    upperLayer.setBorder( new LineBorder( Color.BLACK, 1 ) );
    upperLayer.add( unlockButton );
    upperLayer.setVisible( false );

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setLayout( null );
    layeredPane.setLayer( mainLayer, 0 );
    layeredPane.add( mainLayer );
    layeredPane.setLayer( substrate, 1 );
    layeredPane.add( substrate );
    layeredPane.setLayer( upperLayer, 2 );
    layeredPane.add( upperLayer );

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setBounds( ( screenSize.width - width ) / 2, ( screenSize.height - height ) / 2, width, height );
    frame.add( layeredPane );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }

  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    new LockScreen();
  }
}
```

There are three layers used:

- mainLayer: contents of your application
- substrate: semi-transparent layer to blur the main layer
- upperLayer: a panel with password input form or progress bar

The layer "substrate" is made non-opaque to let the main layer to be visible. Also, substrate consumes mouse events to reject passing them to the main level.

Comment: Hi!Thanks for your reply! I think it is better to lock the windows environment because the application will run in 3 different screens. I want the lock screen to be transparent because the user needs to see what is goin on behind the lock screen.